# MySQL PhpMyAdmin - Unrecognized Keyword CONCAT

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, concatenation

I'm practicing creating a table of password hashes in MySQL using phpMyAdmin. The SQL code I try to enter is:

**Edit:** using the new code I am using:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `salt`, `passwordhash`) 
VALUES ('username', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g', SHA2(CONCAT('password', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g'), 256)));
```

After SHA2, everything is an error, with the first one saying "Unrecognized Keyword. (near CONCAT)." The rest all say "Unrecognized Token" and then whatever string, so it appears all these problems are just caused by CONCAT. Is there another way to concatenate strings?

[image: Screen shot of the current code and errors]

Comment: ***You shouldn't use [SHA1 password hashes](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)***  or ***[MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin and MySQL versions are you using? Once I correct the extra closing parenthesis, this works fine for me using the current phpMyAdmin release (4.6.5.2).

Comment: Also, you could use the "Insert" tab which has a dropdown of MySQL functions which may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should have got

> Error in query (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native
>   function 'SHA2'

This way it is working for me

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `passwordhash` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE='InnoDB' COLLATE 'utf16_bin';

INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `salt`, `passwordhash`) 
VALUES ('username', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g', SHA2('test',CONCAT('password', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g')));

SELECT * FROM user;


username    salt    passwordhash
username    a1b2c3d4e5f6g   9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
username    a1b2c3d4e5f6g   9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really appears like the problem is with CONCAT or something. It says Unrecognized Keyword and everything downstream of that is an error. It also says something about a closing bracket at position 99? (Refer to the screenshot).

I've tried every syntactical combination of all the suggestions in this thread but nothing's worked :/

Answer (score 2):

As per your new code: you have an extra bracket, again in `, 256)));`.

Here:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `salt`, `passwordhash`) 
VALUES ('username', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g', SHA2(CONCAT('password', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g'), 256));
```

This and with all the comments I left up there.

---

**Edit:** The following, as per going through the MySQL manual on `SHA2()` could be a related issue.

As per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2

*This function works only if MySQL has been configured with SSL support. See [Section 6.4, “Using Secure Connections”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/secure-connections.html). 
SHA2() can be considered cryptographically more secure than MD5() or SHA1().
**SHA2() was added in MySQL 5.5.5.***

So, make sure that the MySQL version you are using matches it or is higher than that. If it is lower than 5.5.5, then `SHA2()` isn't available for you to use. That, or it could be an sysadmin / security issue on the server.

Contact the sysadmin at your school if that is where you are running this off from, as it seems from what you said in comments - *"I'm following a school tutorial that said to use SHA2"*. Either way, the MySQL version is important here.

To check the version of MySQL installed, use the following syntax in phpmyadmin:

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Instead of what you used being `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: It literally is not the reason why. I appreciate your help, but I've copy and pasted everyone's different answers, and tried any random fix that could help. You've done a lot for me and are clearly are much more knowledgable, but please stop telling me to accept your answers when it hasn't worked. I can honestly understand if you feel like this is a waste of your time, because it will probably end up being a cache issue (like you stated above). I'm going to try re-logging. In all sincerity though, I do appreciate your time.

Comment: @NicholasHassan I've edited my comment for it and you're right about that.

Comment: @NicholasHassan I don't mind spending the time to help. I just find it rather strange as to why your phpmyadmin is behaving so strangely like that. Make sure your column types and lengths are correct also.

Comment: It still doesn't work after logging in and out and restarting. I have a tutorial today and hopefully it will be better if someone can look at my computer directly. Thanks for all your help - I'm sure that even if they weren't the main problem, all my syntax errors would cause trouble down the road as well.

Comment: @NicholasHassan You're welcome. One thing that comes to mind is that to make sure that the quotes you're using are indeed the correct ones. There may be unicode (invisible) characters introduced somewhere (or unicode quotes). That's all I can think of right now. Other than that, I am stumped.

Comment: @NicholasHassan I've made an additional edit to my answer while reading through the manual on `SHA2()` on mysql.com https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2 and it could be a related problem. Reload it to see under **Edit:**

Comment: why was this downvoted? if you're going to downvote this because you felt it's wrong, then downvote the other ones too. Explain the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

according to MySQL documentation:

> `SHA2(str, hash_length)`
>
> Calculates the SHA-2 family of hash functions (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512). The first argument is the cleartext string to be hashed. The second argument indicates the desired bit length of the result, which must have a value of 224, 256, 384, 512, or 0 (which is equivalent to 256). If either argument is NULL or the hash length is not one of the permitted values, the return value is NULL. Otherwise, the function result is a hash value containing the desired number of bits. See the notes at the beginning of this section about storing hash values efficiently

You need to provide a second parameter to the `SHA2()` function (the hash length) and this argument must be one of the values  224, 256, 384, 512, or 0.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `salt`, `passwordhash`) VALUES ('username', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g', SHA2(CONCAT('password', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g'),256));
```

Comment: [Didn't I already say that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744586/mysql-phpmyadmin-unrecognized-keyword-concat?noredirect=1#comment68715136_40744586)

Comment: *"yes you did, so what ?"* why are you being so snotty about it? OP told me it didn't do a difference. I hope this bites you back, this if you want attitude back.

Comment: wow, keep cool, dude I didn't meant to hurt you... The fact is it's the only problem about his query...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really appears like the problem is with CONCAT or something. It says Unrecognized Keyword and everything downstream of that is an error. It also says something about a closing bracket at position 99? (Refer to the screenshot).

I've tried every syntactical combination of all the suggestions in this thread but nothing's worked :/

Comment: I'm sorry if I hurted you, I beg your pardon for that. It's just I didn't see what you meant by "Didn't I already say that?" @Fred-ii-

Comment: @n00dl3 It's this bit you said: *"so what ?"*. Those aren't very kind words when used together like that ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my natural-speaking language, maybe I should spend more time on [english stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/) ;-) @Fred-ii-

Comment: @NicholasHassan just try with correct `SHA2()` syntax and update your question with the errors you eventualy get.

Comment: @n00dl3 I understand.

Comment: @NicholasHassan I removed extra-bracket in my answer